# Eval variable as HTML in vue

Tags: html, vue.js

It might be basic question,however I can't find the answer and I have no idea it is possible or not.

I am not familliar with `vue`

What I want to do is like this

```
 <html>
 [[parse()]]
 </html>

new Vue({
 methods: {
  parse(){
    return "<div>test</div>"
  }
 }
});
```

Normally it shows the `<div>test<div>` as strings not html tags,

However I want to eval this return variable as html.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?redirect=true#v-html) directive:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    parse() {
      return '<div>test</div>'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-html="parse()"></div>
</div>
```

Make sure you read the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're not using unconstrained user input in your HTML generation which could leave your page vulnerable to injection attacks, you can use the [v-html](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html) directive for this:

```
<div v-html="parse()"></div>
```